# DevOps on Databricks Notebook with specific Path

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am trying to implement azure DevOps on databricks notebook.

My Dev Instance databricks notebooks are integrated with git repository and it is in below folder structure.

[image]

I have created a build pipeline which will detect the changes in the **Databricks** folder for each Code (CodeA and CodeB) using **Trigger** tab in the build pipeline as shown below.

[image]

But at the time of publishing artifacts, how could we select the path to get the databricks files only from each of the Code as shown in the above folder structure?

[image]

If it is not possible if i have to select the parent folder **Code** which includes databricks file for  **CodeA** and  **CodeB** then how can I deploy it into the Shared folder of Databricks UAT instance which is having the below folder structure?

[image]

Ideally it should be as shown in the below diagram.
[image]

Any way to achieve this? Any leads appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just select the parent folder `Code/` which includes databricks file for CodeA and CodeB to publish in the build pipeline.

[image]

Then you need to create a release pipeline and use the third-party task [Databricks Deploy Notebooks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DataThirstLtd.databricksDeployScriptsTasks&targetId=47097972-e633-4284-ad72-fe49f3c8dd5f) to deploy the notebooks.

When you create the [release pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops), Click add to select your build pipeline and add the artifacts

[image]

Add a stage in the release pipeline. Add the task `Databricks Deploy Notebooks` in the stage job.

Click the `3dots` of the `Source files path` field to select the databricks. Enter the `Target files path` of your azure databricks.

Here you can select the path to get each databricks file deployed to its corresponding folder in azure databricks. See below.
[image]

Then configure the Authentication method. See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/authentication#:%7E:text=Generate%20a%20personal%20access%20token,-This%20section%20describes&text=in%20the%20upper%20right%20corner,the%20Generate%20New%20Token%20button.) to get a `databricks bearer token` for the task.

[image]

Add Multiple `Databricks Deploy Notebooks` tasks and change the `Source files path` and `Target files path` field accordingly  to deploy to different databricks.

You can check [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-azure-devops#define-your-release-pipeline) for more information.

Comment: Is there any way to create the folder structure temporarily after the artifact creation and  map files from the source to destination?

Comment: @Antony you can check out [Copy files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy the artifacts to a temporarily folders.

Comment: In the above diagram  for CodeA, we have to write 2 copy files tasks to copy files for 2wheeler and 4wheeler? Or it can be generalized in a single copy file task?

Comment: @Antony I am afraid you have to use 2 copy file tasks. However, it can be done by scripts, you can write  scripts to copy the files on a script task.

Comment: I have added a powershell script to copy all the notebook files from different locations from artifact to the desired folder structure. This is helping me to do the restructuring in a single go